# Prevent Org mode from raising Emacs frame while exporting to PDF

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Some of my org mode files take a long time to export because they include code for number crunching that is executed during export (via Org Babel) .  I usually minimize the Emacs frame while the export process is running and work on something else.  Unfortunately, the Emacs frame is automatically raised during export and I think it happens every time pdflatex is run (three times).  These frames then get in my way and I have to minimize them again and again.  How can I prevent Org mode from raising the frame during export?

**Edit**: Minimal example:

- `emacs -Q`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-initialize`
- <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)`
- Open a new file `test.org` and paste content shown below.
- <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> to export to PDF via LaTeX.
- Immediately minimize Emacs frame using window manager.
- Wait 5 seconds.

Result: Emacs frame raised after ~5s.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results value
(if (sit-for 5)
    "Finished waiting."
  "Interrupted while waiting.")
#+END_SRC
```

**Edit 2:** I'm using Emacs 26.0.60 (compiled from source) with Org mode 9.1.6 (from ELPA) but I have been experiencing this problem with many versions of Emacs and Org mode and for at least three years (before that I didn't use Org's exporting facility).  My window manager is FVWM2 on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

Comment: I previously experienced a similar issue with another library and tracked it down to `select-frame-set-input-focus`, which caused the behavior you described.  I modified the related functions to use `select-frame` and `raise-frame` instead.  You might want to grep the org-babel / pdflatex stuff to see if that function is used ....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I checked in the complete org source and as far as I can see, `select-frame-set-input-focus` is only used in two functions that are unrelated to exporting (`org-eval-in-calendar` and `org-read-date`).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with `emacs-version` 25.1.50.2 i686-pc-linux-gnu gtk+-version 3.10.8, `org-version` 9.1.6 `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`, [`awesome`](https://awesomewm.org/) window manager. That demonstrates how important it is that you add version information to your question. Run `M-x emacs-version` and `M-x org-version` and add the output, add also your os and window manager. Your recipe is incomplete. Per default `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` is set to `t`. With `:exports results` you are asked to confirm the source block execution. That should be added to the recipe.

Comment: Added version information and the setting of `org-confirm-babel-evaluate`.

Comment: I'm also using fvwm2 together with an older version of emacs. I cannot reproduce your problem. Long time ago I prevented _all_ programs to pop up or raise windows (by configuring fvwm2). I think you should try to setup those `Style` options in your `.fvwm2rc`.  Experiment with something like `Style "emacs" IgnoreRestack,GnomeIgnoreHints,EWMHIgnoreStackingOrderHints`. Or try to destroy general popup functionality with: `destroyfunc UrgencyFunc` or `destroyfunc UrgencyDoneFunc` or `destroyfunc EWMHActivateWindowFunc` Or you could ask at the fvwm mailing list.

Comment: @jue, thank you for these suggestions.  Unfortunately none of this helped.  I also tried using another window manager (xfwm4) and there, too, the frame is raised on export. Hm ...

Comment: @jue, wait, IgnoreRestack actually does prevent the frame from being raised, just not the first time.  Weird.

Comment: I too cannot reproduce it:  GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.26) of 2018-01-22,  Org mode version 9.1.6 (release_9.1.6-529-ga16590), Fedora 27 w/Gnome 3.